# Error: Incompatible types? How else could i do this?

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

```
public static int linearSearch(int[] data, int numToFind)
{
     int found=-1;
     for (int x=0;x<data.length;x++){

       **if(data[x] =numToFind)**
       found = x ;

       break;
     }
     return found;
}
```

Where I have my error it says its an incompatible type at `if(data[x]=numToFind)`

Comment: Use `==` to compare, not `=`...

Comment: Unrelated, but make sure both `found = x;` and `break;` are inside a set of `{}` braces. As written, this loop will only ever run once. Whether the first number in the array matches or not, you `break;` and that ends the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `if` condition it should be `boolean` value. You made just a typo, it should be:

```
if (data[x] == numToFind)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF statement in java expects boolean. Your code should be

```
if(data[x] ==numToFind)
```

This might been a Typo.

> A mistake users from C background frequently make is confusing the assignment and equality operators = and ==. If you want to compare two values, you should use a double equal sign since that's how Java works. If you accidentally use a single equal sign, you don't compare values but assign a value to a variable.
>   Your code would have perfectly worked in C, but it won't work in Java

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `if(data[x] == numToFind)`.

With one = it is **assignment**. With two it is **boolean** **operator**.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int linearSearch(int data[], int numToFind)
{
     int found=-1;
     for (int x=0;x<data.length;x++){

       if(data[x] == numToFind)
       found = x ;

       break;
     }
     return found;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Heheh, but no. the problem is the operator he uses to compare(= and not ==)

Comment: solution just == , whatever not throwing error can't be a solution (wrt data[] and earlier answer) !!!